# Disable file locks on a read-only Windows File Share

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-sharing, windows-server-2016, cifs

## Case

On a Windows Server (2012R2 or 2016), I want to configure a file share offering a following functionality

- some users, `publishers` group, have a write access to the share; these users are managing and updating the content on the share
- other users, `readers` group, have a read-only access to the share; they read the content in a frequent or massive scale

The read-only permission is configured correctly on both the share level and the file system level.

## Problem

The users from `readers` group, or namely their application, are able to open the file for reading and lock these files in the same time, preventing them from being overwritten by `publishers` group.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: If you are connecting mac to the windows file share, here is one possible solution: https://www.acronis.com/en-us/mobility/mac-windows-compatibility/

Comment: I am using exactly this feature with one specific file - it is updated by a script, and even if a user has this file opened, the script can overwrite it, since the user has only read access to the file. Did you check the permissions on the files inside the folder? Maybe the permissions are not inherited correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see the open files via `net files` on the server?

If so, you could try using `net file <ID> /close`.

I would also try replacing an open file via `copy /Y`, that way our could check if only the publishers application behaves like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no "publisher application" involved, just a pure file overwrite. Closing file connections won't solve the issue as clients are rapidly reconnecting to the files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried

```
Set-smbclientconfiguration -oplocksdisabled $true

Set-smbclientconfiguration -useopportunisticlocking $false
```

https://smeitguy.wordpress.com/2016/05/14/oplocks-in-windows-server-2012-r2/